# php login unable to retrieve the right data

Tags: php, authentication

I can't figure out what's wrong with this part of my phpscript. Login is successful but I can't retrieve the data from the right account. Can anyone see if there is something wrong with this part of the script?

```
            $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
            $_SESSION['profiel'] = $rij['Type'];
            $_SESSION['gebruikerID'] = $rij ['Account_nr']; 
            // Gebruiker succesvol ingelogd, gegevens opslaan in sessie enzo ...
            if(strcmp($rij['Type'],"bedrijf")==0){
                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM account_bedrijf WHERE Account_nr = '" . $_SESSION['gebruikerID'] . "limit 1' ";
                $result2 = mysql_query( $query2 ) or trigger_error( mysql_error() );
                if( mysql_num_rows( $result2 ) == 0 ) {
                    session_unset();
                    echo 'Ongeldige gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord';
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['company'] = $result->Bedrijf_nr;
                    header( 'Location: company_profile.php' ) ;
```

Comment: What do you get? Are you getting wrong users data?

Comment: That looks like a Dutch script :p

Comment: yes, it seems like I ain't getting the required data from the asked account. It just places some random information from my database in the company_profile (which isn't from the logged in account)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM account_bedrijf WHERE Account_nr = '" . $_SESSION['gebruikerID'] . "limit 1' ";
```

Will produce following SQL statement (if the gebruikerID is 5):

```
SELECT * FROM account_bedrijf WHERE Account_nr = '5limit 1'
```

You forgot to insert a space and didn't put the id between single quotes. More correct would be:

```
SELECT * FROM account_bedrijf WHERE Account_nr = '" . $_SESSION['gebruikerID'] . "' limit 1";
```

This will produce a more correct

```
SELECT * FROM account_bedrijf WHERE Account_nr = '5' limit 1
```

Comment: But note that the field `Account_nr` sounds like a numerical value, where as now it is approached like it is a textual/enum value. If `Account_nr` is indeed a numerical attribute, drop the enclosing quotes from the above code sample :)

Comment: Might I ask why you use the "limit 1" at the end of your SQL statement? Your Account_Nr sounds like a Primary Key which should already be unique, so you don't need to filter out the first result you get.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the code. A bit i put mysql_error so you can see if you got mysql error happening.

```
   <?php
    $_SESSION['ingelogd'] = true;
    $_SESSION['profiel'] = $rij['Type'];
    $_SESSION['gebruikerID'] = $rij['Account_nr'];
    // Gebruiker succesvol ingelogd, gegevens opslaan in sessie enzo ...
    if (strcmp($rij['Type'], "bedrijf") == 0)
    {
        // Define variables
        $session_var = $_SESSION['gebruikerID'];
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM account_bedrijf WHERE Account_nr='$session_var' LIMIT 1";
        // Do the query // use mysql error for debugging
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 0)
        {
            session_unset();
            echo 'Ongeldige gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord';

        } else
        {
            $_SESSION['company'] = $result->Bedrijf_nr;
            header('Location: company_profile.php');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: ok thanks. I replaced it with your script but it gave the same results. Perhaps the problems is elsewhere, but I am unable to find it. Perhaps it's a detail. I can use the login whith a registered account, but the information of the account isn't shown in company_profile.php . So perhaps there must be something wrong in?:  $_SESSION['company'] = $result->Bedrijf_nr;
            header('Location: company_profile.php');